# Passing parameters between HTML5 pages in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

Here is the situation:

I have a HTML5 demo application. My database is an external JSON file. In the first page (soon after log in) the data is read from the JSON through GetJSON command and rendered into an interactive graph.

The user's choice of data is captured in an integer array which saves the primary key of each chosen item.

The next page needs to perform extract all the details of the selected items and draw up a comparison.

I have two choices:

1. Construct a JSON of selected patient data and pass it two the next page
2. Pass the array holding the selected primary keys, do another GetJSON with the entire data.

**Questions**

1. Which is a better choice?
2. How do you pass javascript arrays/JSON objects between pages?

Comment: Why do you need to have multiple web pages, why can't you just use a single web page?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage

Comment: @Maz - I am trying just that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told by Maz, the best approach to this situation is to put it all in the same page! There is no problem of passing the values!

Also the earlier done settings are maintained as we do not navigate to a different page.

I have put in the graph in one div and put the drill down details in another div.

I selectively hide and un hide these divs.